# SharePoint 2013 Page Views

Tags: usage-counters

I've just noticed in SPO in Office 365, in the pages library they show page views.

[image: SPO Page Views]

Any ideas how one would go about getting that via REST or another method to display that in the page layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use REST API and managed properties to get page views

For recently viewed page you can use "ViewsRecent" and while "ViewsLifeTime" is update every 14 or 15 days.

You can use [SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) to generate REST queries on the fly and refine searches

[image]

```
https://some-SharePoint-online-tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&rowlimit=10&sortlist='viewsrecent:descending'
```

Good luck!

Comment: do you know, how I can get this by c#?

Comment: The SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool lives on GitHub now: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool