# Viewslifetime is getting blank when we hit the sharepoint page using rest search api. It is giving data length 0 for some of the SharePoint pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, search-api

We need to display viewslifetime (page view count) in our SharePoint page using search API. But when we are hitting the search API query it is giving data for some of the sharepoint pages. but when it comes to older sharepoint pages (2018). it is not displaying data. We have filter the query on the basis of sharepoint page URL to display viewslifetime(page view count).

API - URL/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='f3c91631-eff1-4f7b-aa2e-dcb2cbe377de'&selectproperties='ViewsLifeTime,PublishingStatusOWSTEXT,Path,Title'&refinementfilters='Path:("URL*")'

Please let us know if this is the correct API.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that managed properties are searchable, queryable, and wait for a full crawl.

You can use SharePoint [2013 Search Query Tool](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool) to generate REST queries on the fly and refine searches.

Similar issue for your reference:

[SharePoint 2013 Page Views](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112779/sharepoint-2013-page-views)

If you could access Admin center, refer to the site usage reports article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/sharepoint-site-usage?redirectSourcePath=%252fclient%252fSharePoint-site-usage-4ecfb843-e5d5-464d-8bf6-7ed512a9b213&view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Thanks for the reply.